# Data sharing on multiple angular apps

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular7, web-deployment-project

Seeking your advice on effective ways of sharing data in between multiple angular apps (not multiple apps in one project. multiple war file).

1. Local storage has few limitations
2. Url driven approach is not good for keeping json like data

Can i have the best possible options ?

Thanks
Nuwan

Comment: Well it is not clear what you mean by "sharing data" but using Web Sockets may be an option.

Comment: Thanks Eldar. For an example one angular application is loading list of cities  for a drop down. Same set of data is required for second application. then again we have to load the same data set. is there a way to share them ?.